# Regex: find text between @ and the first occuring space/sign

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to find a pattern in a string.

Input is: `Could you do that for me @jdoe?`

Expected result: `@jdoe`

Requirements:

- Needs to start with @ sign
- Needs to stop at space or special characters like ,.?! `hello @jdoe, how are you?`
- Also needs to stop at end of sentence like `hello @jdoe`
- Minimum length is after @ sign is 1 character
- Characters after @ sign are a-z or A-Z or both

What i've got at the moment is: `@([^"]*)([^\s]+)`

This regex does start with the @ sign, stops after a space but continues whenever I keep on typing after that first occurring space sign. Can someone help me trying to find a way to create a regex which suits my requirements?

Comment: Try `@\S+\b`. Are these Twitter mentions?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perhaps @[a-zA-Z]+\b would be better? To prevent matching something like @#a

Comment: @Marathon55 I do not know what can be better in the current scenario, from what I see, OP parses XML/HTML code, and that is not quite correct. I do not know what the real specs for the extracted strings is. Perhaps, `@\w+` is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick one you can play with:

`@\w+`

https://regex101.com/r/ZuifZb/1

Be aware that \w matches a-z A-Z 0-9 and _.

If you only want a-z A-Z, you can use:

`@[a-zA-Z]+`

If you don't want 'Hello @test1' to be a match (@test), you can use negative lookahead:

`@[a-zA-Z]+(?!\w)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex condition you can try for your problem, it triggers whenever there is a @ in the statement and stops after a space or end of statement.

`` str.lastIndexOf(`@`) != -1 && /^\S*$/ig.test(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(`@`) + 1, str.length)) ``

the above code in js compatible, you can change the basic function for any language you want.